# How to implement Auto-date functionality in the Lightning JS

Tags: lightning, community, lightninginput

I would like to show the auto date format like `mm/dd/yy`...with auto `add /`.
I would like to implement exact same functionality shown in the below example from Fiddle.

Here is the example: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6mnpc1j/).

Comment: WHat have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `lightning:input` together with its `onchange` attribute:

```
<--! yourComponent.cmp -->
<aura:component>
    <lightning:input name="customInput" maxlength="10" onchange="{!c.onCustomInputChange}"/>
</aura:component>

<--! yourComponentController.js -->
({
    onCustomInputChange: function (component, event, helper) {
       helper.validateAndReplace(component, event);
    },
});

<--! yourComponentHelper.js -->
({
    validateAndReplace: function (component, event) {
        const input = event.getSource();
        const inputValue = input.get('v.value');
        const validValue = inputValue.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g,'$1/$2')
            .replace(/^(\d\d\/\d\d)(\d+)$/g,'$1/$2')
            .replace(/[^\d\/]/g,'');
        input.set('v.value', validValue);
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, above one is working. how to show a date-picker with the above working functionality.

Comment: Specify the attributes for `lightning:input` `type="date"` `dateStyle="short"`

Comment: I already tried the above mentioned suggestion, then its not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" ?

Comment: if i am including type="date" dateStyle="short" then auto add / is not working and the error i am getting is Uncaught Action failed: c:dateFormatAuto$controller$onCustomInputChange [Cannot read property 'replace' of null]

Answer (score 0):

`ui:inputDate` already has format attribute. You can utilize that one for auto format.

```
<ui:inputDate aura:id="EndDateField" value="" displayDatePicker="true" format="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
```

Modified:

As `ui:inputDate` is going to deprecated soon,  lightning:input can be used in it's place. Use **dateStyle** attribute as short to make in format like **1/7/2019**.

```
<lightning:input aura:id="dob" type="date" name="accdob" dateStyle="short" label="Date of Birth" value="{!v.account.DOB__c}" />
```

Check complete documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation).

**Update 2:**

You can implement same code in lightning as well.

component:

```
<lightning:input type="date" aura:id="Birthdate" dateStyle="short"  name="Birthdate" maxlength="10" onchange="{!c.onChange}"/>
```

JS Controller:

```
    onChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    var dob = component.find("Birthdate");
    var dateValue = dob.get('v.value');
    var formattedValue=dateValue.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/^(\d\d\/\d\d)(\d+)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/[^\d\/]/g,'');
    dob.set('v.value',formattedValue);
   }
```

Comment: I won't recommend use of ui:inputDate as it would be deprecated soon
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/4-salesforce-summer-19-updates-developers-should-know-jie-tan

Comment: Thank you for sharing this link.

Comment: dateStyle="short" will only work if we select from the date-picker, if we enter it manually in the input field then it will not going to work. @DhanikLalSahni

Comment: Check Update 2 for same kind of functionality.

Comment: it only works when we enter the date manually. it doesn't have the functionality to select from the date picker i want both functionality should work if we enter it manually or either by selecting the date from date-picker.

Comment: Changed component code little bit.

Comment: I already tried the above suggested one. its not able to add auto / when we enter the some number manually in input field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97628/discussion-between-alok-jha-and-dhanik-lal-sahni).

Answer (score 0):

The desired functionality i was able to achieve through ui:inputdate.

**Component**

```
<div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-page-header__title slds-truncate">
    <lightning:icon iconName="action:new_task" alternativeText="Approved"/>
    <h1 class="slds-m-left_large">AutoSlash</h1>
</div>   

<div class="slds-grid  slds-gutters slds-align_absolute-center">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12">
        <label>OnKeyUp :</label>
        <ui:inputDate aura:id="inputData" value="{!v.DOB}" format="MM/dd/yyyy" displayDatePicker="true" keyup="{!c.onChange}" change="{!c.onChange}" updateOn="keyup,change" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JSController**

```
({
onChange : function(component, event){
    var seperator = "/";
    var lengthTtl;
    var curntVal;

    curntVal = component.find("inputData").get('v.value');
    lengthTtl = curntVal.length;
    if(lengthTtl == 2 || lengthTtl == 5) {
        curntVal += seperator;
        component.set('v.DOB',curntVal);
    }
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
        if((e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <=90) || (e.keyCode >= 106 && e.keyCode <=123) || (e.keyCode >= 186 && e.keyCode <=192) || (e.keyCode >= 219 && e.keyCode <=222)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }); 
},
```

})